# Push/Assign JSON child string to respective parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON string which is generated from an API.

```
[{"categories":{"category":{"id":"1","Name":"furit"}}},{"categories":{"category":{"id":"2","Name":"veg"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"1","Name":"fruit"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"2","Name":"pears"}}}]
```

how can I push all child values to their parent to look something like this.

```
[{"categories":{"category":[{"id":"1","name":"fruit"},{"id":"2","name":"veg"}]}},{"products":{"products":[{"id":"1","name":"apple"},{"id":"2","name":"pears"}]}}]
```

Thanks.

### Updated data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new object and use map to change your data structure and assign that data to new object.

```js
var data = [{"categories":{"category":{"id":"1","Name":"furit"}}},{"categories":{"category":{"id":"2","Name":"veg"}}}]
  
var r = {
  categories: {
    category: data.map(o => o.categories.category)
  }
}
console.log(r)
```

**Updated** For new data structure you can use `forEach()` loop and add to object.

```js
var data = [{"categories":{"category":{"id":"1","Name":"furit"}}},{"categories":{"category":{"id":"2","Name":"veg"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"1","Name":"fruit"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"2","Name":"pears"}}}]

var r = {categories: {category: []}, products: {product: []}}
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(e.categories) r.categories.category.push(e.categories.category)
  if(e.products) r.products.product.push(e.products.product)
})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: nice. very clean. what if a similar "products" object was on the data array, how would i map that?

Comment: Could you show example of data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)**, it will reduce all your array items `category` objects in a single `categories` array, giving the expected results

Your code should look like this:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[0].categories.push(b.categories);
  return a;
}, [{
  categories: []
}]);
```

Or if you want an `object` as result instead of an `array` use it like this:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a.categories.push(b.categories);
  return a;
}, {
  categories: []
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    "categories": {
      "category": {
        "id": "1",
        "Name": "furit"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "categories": {
      "category": {
        "id": "2",
        "Name": "veg"
      }
    }
  }
];

var result = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[0].categories.push(b.categories);
  return a;
}, [{
  categories: []
}]);

console.log(result);
```

## Edit:

This is an edit after adding `products` to your initial object:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if(b.categories)
      a[0].categories.push(b.categories);
   if(b.products)   
       a[0].products.push(b.products);
  return a;
}, [{
  categories: [],
  products : []
}]);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{"categories":{"category":{"id":"1","Name":"furit"}}},{"categories":{"category":{"id":"2","Name":"veg"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"1","Name":"fruit"}}},{"products":{"product":{"id":"2","Name":"pears"}}}]
;

var result = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if(b.categories)
      a[0].categories.push(b.categories);
   if(b.products)   
       a[0].products.push(b.products);
  return a;
}, [{
  categories: [],
  products : []
}]);

console.log(result);
```